# get and output a substring from withn an email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

in an email template i am getting the 18 char SFDC ID, but most users are only familiar with the 15 chars. from withn the email template, can i output only that?

Comment: Can you use the LEFT function to return the first 15 characters? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LEFT function, such as `{!LEFT(Account.Id, 15)}`. Alternatively, you could just let them see the 18 character ID, because either one works for accessing the record (e.g. na1.salesforce.com/0011000000j3jLA is the same as na1.salesforce.com/0011000000j3jLAAAD).

Comment: that was the syntax i was looking for. thanks!! that's formula field syntax? as a rule of thumb can i use that in VF?

Comment: @nivyaj With the exceptions noted in [Formula Operators and Functions - Salesforce.com Help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US) (see individual functions for restrictions), you can use any formula listed on this page. For example, `PRIORVALUE` isn't available in VF, but `LOWER` is.